# How to wrap or truncate long strings in a Material-UI ExpansionPanelSummary

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to create an `ExpansionPanel` where the summary might be a quite long string of unbroken characters (i.e. no hyphens, no spaces).

When I tried it out, the `ExpansionPanelSummary` component displays poorly on a narrow width display - it overwrites the button and overflows off-screen.

Here is my example, forked from the [ExpansionPanel](https://material-ui.com/demos/expansion-panels/) Material-UI demo, shrink the width of the output frame and you can see the email addresses don't wrap and look ugly: https://codesandbox.io/s/wqm5k3vmyw
[image]

I've tried using `nowrap` on the `Typography` to get it to clip (my preferred solution):

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
  <Typography nowrap className={classes.heading}>
    areallyreallylongaddress@email.example.com
  </Typography>
</ExpansionPanelSummary>
```

I've also tried adding a style `overflowWrap: "break-word"` to force it to wrap anywhere, not just on hyphens or whitespace.

The best I've been able to do is to get the text to not overflow outside the expansion panel itself by adding `style={{ textOverflow: "ellipsis", overflow: "hidden" }}` to the `ExpansionPanel` (see the second example from the linked example).

Ideally, I'd like it to function by truncating from the right of the context, showing an ellipsis and not overwriting the expand icon.
How can I do that with `ExpansionPanel`?

Failing that, how can I just force it to word-wrap?

I'm using material-UI v3.4.0 and the problem is visible on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 49):

From the official docs: https://material-ui.com/api/typography/

> noWrap: If true, the text will not wrap, but instead will truncate with a text overflow ellipsis.
> Note that text overflow can only happen with block or inline-block level elements (the element needs to have a width in order to overflow).

Note the capital 'W' in 'noWrap'.

```
<Typography noWrap className={classes.heading}>
  areallyreallylongaddress@email.example.com
</Typography>
```

Comment: You need to set a width on the container to be able to truncate the text inside...

Comment: This approach did not work for me. I had to use the manual CSS / JSS styling approach suggested by Joel in this thread.

Comment: Is there a way of setting how many rows/lines before truncation?

Comment: I thin [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324014/4756173) covers how to do it with more than one line truncation.

Answer (score 25):

Suggest that you wrap your Typography element with a div that is styled with textOverflow: "ellipsis", for example:

```
<div style={{overflow: "hidden", textOverflow: "ellipsis", width: '11rem'}}> 
  <Typography nowrap className={classes.heading}>
    areallyreallylongaddress@email.example.com
  </Typography>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working because you set the width of the parent!

Comment: Ok, well that is good to know, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: How do you deal with responsive elements which have not a specific width?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I solved it:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  summary: {
    overflow: 'hidden'
  }
}))

// ... snipped ...

const classes = useStyles()

// ... snipped ...

<ExpansionPanelSummary classes={{ content: classes.summary }} expandIcon={<SomeIcon />}>
  <Typography noWrap title={experiment.name}>{longTextHere}</Typography>
</ExpansionPanelSummary>
```

Instead of applying the style to the `ExpansionPanelSummary` component itself, apply it to the "inner content".

Answer (score 3):

To wrap (*not* truncate with ellipse) text inside a material / MUI button:

```
<LoadingButton
  sx={{
    fontSize: {
      lg: 12,
      md: 11,
      sm: 10,
      xs: 10
    },
    wordWrap: 'break-word',
    width: '11rem',
  }}>
  <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'normal'}}> 
    My Button Text
  </div>
</LoadingButton>
```

The `width: '11rem'` will keep the width of the buttons consistent against varying text sizes, but words will still wrap without it (but inconsistently based on text width).

The `fontSize` sx helpers are handy to scale down your text based on screen width.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering how to do it for more than one line truncation, then [this other answer by @David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324014/4756173) covers it:

```js
<Typography
   sx={{
      overflow: 'hidden',
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      display: '-webkit-box',
      WebkitLineClamp: '2',
      WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
   }}
>
</Typography>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to wrap the text to newline use:-

```
<Box component="div" whiteSpace="normal">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
</Box>
```