# Material ui text ellipsis after two line

Tags: material-ui

How can I ellipsis a text after two line in material ui?

Here https://material-ui.com/system/display/#text-overflow show for single line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Comment: Can you show me how can I do it in MUI?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `makeStyles` function to create a `multiLineEllipsis` style.

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const LINES_TO_SHOW = 2;

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924997/8062659
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  multiLineEllipsis: {
    overflow: "hidden",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    display: "-webkit-box",
    "-webkit-line-clamp": LINES_TO_SHOW,
    "-webkit-box-orient": "vertical"
  }
});
```

Then you use this style just like as below

```js
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Typography className={classes.multiLineEllipsis}>
      Very long text here.
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit practical-microservice-0mexz]

Answer (score 24):

Update using `sx`:

```js
<Typography
   sx={{
      overflow: 'hidden',
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      display: '-webkit-box',
      WebkitLineClamp: '2',
      WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
   }}
>
</Typography>
```

Comment: Worked for me! Although IntelliSense was not showing '-webkit-box' as a possible value for display...

Comment: Could not get this working when added padding to text. So removed padding and it works fine.  Thanks!